# How to query a specific changeset build on TFS by GUI?

Tags: tfs

I need to build a specific changeset on TFS, but the "Query new build" dialog let me choose only "Latest sources" or shelveset...
Running TFS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but it could work.

When you queue a new build, you can go to the Parameters tab. When you expand the Advanced group, you have the Get Version property. See http://readcommit.blogspot.com/2008/06/building-specific-version-with-team.html for how you can enter the values in there.